# 2 items in a cell with same tapGestureRecognizer (swift)

Tags: swift, tableview, uigesturerecognizer

in my app i have a tableview with a profile image and a username label. If you click on one of the 2 then the need to do this function:

```
 func goToProfileScreen(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("profile", sender: nil)
 }
```

however if i try to implement this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath it only works for the last time i've added it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell") as? NewsCell {
            let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]

            cell.request?.cancel()

            let profileTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsVC.goToProfileScreen(_:)))
            profileTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            // profileTapRecognizer.delegate = self

            cell.profileImg.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.profileImg.userInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.profileImg.addGestureRecognizer(profileTapRecognizer)

            cell.usernameLabel.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.usernameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.usernameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(profileTapRecognizer)

            var img: UIImage?

            if let url = post.profileImageURL {
                if url != "" {
                    img = NewsVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
                }
            }

            cell.configureCell(post, img: img)
            cell.selectionStyle = .None

            return cell

        } else {

            return NewsCell()
        }
    }
```

so now it works for the username label. if i put the usernamelabel first in the code and then the profileImg, then it only works for the profileImg?

how can i get it to work for both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 2 different tapRecognizers, because a UITapGestureRecognizer can only be attached to **one** view.
("They are objects that you attach to **a** view", [Apple Doku](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer))

```
let profileTapRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsVC.goToProfileScreen(_:)))
let profileTapRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsVC.goToProfileScreen(_:)))
profileTapRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
profileTapRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

// profileTapRecognizer1.delegate = self
// profileTapRecognizer2.delegate = self

cell.profileImg.tag = indexPath.row
cell.profileImg.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.profileImg.addGestureRecognizer(profileTapRecognizer1)

cell.usernameLabel.tag = indexPath.row
cell.usernameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.usernameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(profileTapRecognizer2)
```

Comment: Gonna try it thx. I never tried it because i thought it was to much code and repeating for the same answer.. But ok :)

Comment: Got it, and it works :) why do they have to do it this way? it would be so much easier and quicker if you could just use the same gestureRecognizer...